# Error: "migrate dev is not a prisma command." when calling `npx prisma migrate dev --preview-feature`

Tags: migration, prisma

When I run the following command:

```
npx prisma migrate dev --preview-feature
```

I get the following error:

```
$ npx prisma migrate dev --preview-feature
npx: installed 600 in 26.334s
 ▸    migrate dev is not a prisma command.
 ▸    Perhaps you meant generate
 ▸    Run prisma help for a list of available commands.

Get in touch if you need help: https://slack.prisma.io
To get more detailed output, run $ set -x DEBUG "*"
(node:6096) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

However, the `prisma migrate dev` command should be available in the [Prisma CLI](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference/#migrate-dev). Why doesn't this work?

Comment: How is this related to the <sql> _language_?

Comment: Prisma Migrate is a SQL migration tool, but you're right this particular question is not related to SQL. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, I accidentally invoked the Prisma 1 CLI which is available as the [`prisma` package on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prisma).

The way to fix this is to make sure that the Prisma 2 CLI which is available as the [`@prisma/cli` package on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@prisma/cli) is installed locally (see [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-cli/installation#local-installation-recommended)):

```
npm install @prisma/cli --save-dev
# or
yarn add @prisma/cli --dev
```

That way [`npx` will execute the right binary from the local `node_modules` folder](https://github.com/npm/npx#description).

From the `npx` docs:

> Executes `<command>` either from a `local node_modules/.bin`, or from a central cache, installing any packages needed in order for `<command>` to run.
>
> By default, `npx` will check whether `<command>` exists in `$PATH`, or in the local project binaries, and execute that. If `<command>` is not found, it will be installed prior to execution.
>
> Unless a `--package` option is specified, `npx` will try to guess the name of the binary to invoke depending on the specifier provided. All package specifiers understood by npm may be used with `npx`, including git specifiers, remote tarballs, local directories, or scoped packages.

If for some reason the local binary is not picked up, you can try to add the `prisma` script to your `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts":  {
    "prisma": "prisma"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting `The package @prisma/cli has been renamed to prisma.`

Comment: In my terminal I added `npm install prisma` and dit not audit the packages that worked for now